# mysqli num rows in multi query

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to monitor num_rows for each query when executing a multi_query in MySQL, for example:

```
    $query= "SELECT * FROM `table1`;";
    $query.= "SELECT * FROM `table2`;";
    $display='';

    if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
        do {  
            if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
                $display.='<div>first table results</div>';  
                while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
                    $display.='<div>'.$row->id.'</div>';      
                }
                $result->free();
            }
            if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
                $display.='<div>second table results</div>';
            }
        } while ($mysqli->next_result());
    }
    else{
        echo $mysqli->error; exit(); 
    }
```

I need to know separately for each table whether the query had results and display something like:

```
$display='<div>No results for table 1</div>';
$display='<div>No results for table 2</div>';
```

Comment: Shouldn't you separate the queries with a comma-dot (`;`)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the code works just fine

Comment: Sure, because it is interpreted as a single query.

Comment: Sorry about that, they are separated in the original code I just posted a quick example here

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd use $display as an array to hold the results.  I've extended the do while condition.  Your error check was only going to be triggered if the first query was bad, I've moved it outside of the multi_query if statement.

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM `table1`;";
$query.= "SELECT * FROM `table2`;";
$display=array();
$tableno=0;

if($mysqli->multi_query($query)){
    do{
        if($result=$mysqli->store_result()){
            ++$tableno;
            while($row=$result->fetch_object()){
                $display[$tableno].='<div>'.$row->id.'</div>';      
            }
            $result->free();
        }
    } while($mysqli->more_results() && $mysqli->next_result());
}
if($error_mess=$mysqli->error){$display[++$tableno]="<div>Error: $error_mess</div>";}

print_r($display);  //should provide all results/errors grouped by query
```